# git log --numstat has weird data

Tags: git, git-log

I run this command:

```
git log HEAD --numstat --pretty="%ae" | cat
```

and I see this:

```
6       4       frontend/src/Frontend.hs
aviansys@gmail.com
dan.side@gmail.com
dan.side@avian.systems

3       3       dep/rhyolite/github.json
29      14      frontend/src/Frontend.hs
aviansys@gmail.com

3       1       backend/src/Backend/RequestHandler.hs
27      18      frontend/src/Frontend.hs
dan.side@avian.systems

5       0       default.nix
7       0       dep/reflex-dom/default.nix
7       0       dep/reflex-dom/github.json
7       0       dep/reflex/default.nix
7       0       dep/reflex/github.json
dan.side@avian.systems
dan.side@avian.systems
dan.side@avian.systems
```

what exactly does it mean to have more than one email associated with a commit? does that likely mean the person moved from one network to another (like took their laptop home, then finished their commit?) I am trying to parse the commits and assign them to a single author, but having multiple emails attached to a commit is making this harder?

Comment: Side note: if you're using `| cat` to defeat the pager, note that you can use `git --no-pager`.

Comment: ah yes, I was using cat to do that, but if you aren't in a terminal, it can tell so don't need either cat or --no-pager tmk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are seeing a commit with multiple addresses? It looks to me that you are seeing commits with *no* numstat-worthy changes (e.g. merges).

What happens if you say "%h %ae %s" instead of just "%ae"?

Comment: so to be productive, is there a git log flag I can use to ignore the "empty merge commits" like `git log --ignore-merge-commits` or something something?

Answer (score 3):

As you have already found, you are including merges in your `git log` output.  By default, when looking at a merge, `git log` *does not* diff the merge against its parents, so no `--numstat` output comes out either.

Skipping the merges (with `git log --no-merges`) is ... okay, but if you do this, you lose information about any changes made during merging.  That might be the best you can do, because the information you *can* get from a merge is tricky.

Consider a graph that looks like this:

```
...--o--A
         \
          M--...
         /
...--o--B
```

Git will compare `M` against ... what?  A standard `git diff` compares *two* commits.  Which two commits should you compare, to make sense of the snapshot in `M`?  Is it `A`-vs-`M`, or `B`-vs-`M`?

There is no one right answer to this question.  To avoid having to pick an answer, `git log` just doesn't bother diffing `M` at all, by default.  But you can tell it that it *should* diff anyway, using any of these three options:

- `-c`: produce a combined diff
- `--cc` (two dashes, two lowercase Cs): produce a combined diff
- `-m`: produce multiple non-combined diffs by "virtually splitting" the merge

The two kinds of combined diffs are not exactly the same, but I've never seen a proper description of the intent of the difference between them.  Both of them first throw out, from the diff, *any* file whose copy in `M` exactly matches its copy in either `A` *or* `B`.  (If the merge has more than two parents, this phase discards any file that exactly matches the copy in *any* parent.)

Then, having reduced the number of files—sometimes to zero!—the combined diff goes on to diff *both* (or all) parents' versions against the (single) child version of that file in commit `M`.  See [the `git diff` documentation on combined merges](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree#_combined_diff_format) for more.

The `-m` option is more useful, especially if combined with the `--first-parent` option.  In this case, Git pretends—for `diff` purposes only—that `M` has been split into multiple separate copies:

```
...--o--A--M1--...

...--o--B--M2--...
```

Now that the merge has been split, each copy has just one parent, so Git can, in effect, just use `git diff A M1` and show you that.  Then it can go on and `git diff B M2` and show you that.  The actual snapshot used in each diff is just the (single) snapshot for real commit `M`.

If you combine this with `--first-parent`, `git log` walks only the *first* parent of each merge, and produces only the first-parent diff for the merge.  So instead of the actual graph, this `git log` shows you what things would be if the graph were just:

```
...--o--A
         \
          M--...
```

You never see commit `B` (nor its parents) at all, but you *do* get a diff describing commit `M`, as compared to commit `A`, and therefore `--numstat` works for this case.